# Writing RDF by importing namespaces from a loaded ontologies in jena?

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, jena, ontology

I'm planning to write and store lots of data in RDF format. I'll be using SIOC, GEO and dcterms. In Jena, is there a way to import the namespaces from loaded ontologies instead of doing, for example, the following:

```java
model.setNsPrefix("sioc","http://sioc.com/ontologies/sioc#");
Property  ID = model.createProperty("http://sioc.com/ontologies/sioc#" + "ID");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use the string based approach, though I'd strongly recommend something like:

```java
String SIOC = "http://sioc.com/ontologies/sioc#";
model.setNsPrefix("sioc",SIOC );
Property  ID = model.createProperty( SIOC + "ID" );
```

to save some typing and possible typos.  For many common vocabularies, Jena already has predefined vocabulary classes that define a bunch of useful constants.  Most of these live in the [com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/package-summary.html) package.  For instance, in [`DCTerms`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/DCTerms.html) there are constants such as [`creator`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/vocabulary/DCTerms.html#creator) so that you can do things like

```java
Resource r = ...;
r.addProperty( DCTerms.creator, ... );
```

Of course, Jena can only predefine so many of these classes.  For others, you can use Jena's [schemagen](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/tools/schemagen.html) to generate those kinds of classes.   It's a command line tool (but you can also call it programmatically, I believe), and pass it the RDF or OWL file that defines the vocabulary, and you get a `.java` file back that constants constants for all the properties, classes, and individuals in the vocabulary.  You can get simple Model-based resources, or OntModel-based resources, too.  It's quite configurable, and I've used in a number of projects.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you can use the following plugin.

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
            <artifactId>jena-maven-tools</artifactId>
            <version>0.8</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>src/main/resources/ontologies/*.owl</include>
                    <include>src/main/resources/ontologies/*.rdf</include>
                </includes>
                <fileOptions>
                    <source>
                        <input>default</input>
                        <package-name>com.example.ontology</package-name>
                    </source>
                    <source>
                        <input>src/main/resources/ontologies/*.owl</input>
                        <include>src/main/resources/ontologies/*.rdf</include>
                        <ontology>true</ontology>
                    </source>
                </fileOptions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>schemagen</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>translate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

when you run maven compile, you can find all the Resources and Properties in the OWL/RDF file is converted to Constants in the respective class with the OWL/RDF filename. so, you can call them in your code with something like, OWLFILENAME.RESOURCE or OWLFILENAME.PROPERTY.